# Is it smart to output data from embedded device in xml format?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, embedded

Our company makes many embedded devices that communicate with PC's via applications that I write in C#.net. I have been considering different ways of improving the data transfer so that the PC application can be more easily synchronized with the devices current state (which in some cases is continually changing).

I have been thinking about an approach where the device formats it's description and state messages into an xml formatted message before sending them across either the serial port, USB, Ethernet Socket, etc.  I was thinking that it may make the process of getting all of this data into my C# classes more simple.

The alternative is an approach where the host application sends a command like GETSTATUS and the device responds with an array of bytes, each representing a different property, sensor reading, etc.

I don't have a great deal of experience with xml but from what I have seen can be done with LINQ to XML it seems like it might be a good idea. What do you guys think? Is this something that is done commonly? Is it a horrible idea?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, which ever way you go, make sure the returned data has a version number embedded so that you can revise the data structure.

Is both an option?  Seriously, there are always situations where sending data in a more readable form are preferable, and others where a more dense representation is best (these are fewer than most people think, but I don't want to start a religious war about it).  People will passionately argue for both, because they are optimizing for different things.  Providing both options would satisfy both camps.

A nice, clear XML status could definitely lower the bar for people who are starting to work with your devices. You could also build a C# object that can be deserialized from the binary data that is returned.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a terrible idea, but it is probably an overdedesign. I would prefer to use a format that the embedded device will generate easier and faster. Then at the PC side I would insert a layer to conver it to a convenient format. You can also use LINQ with objects. Why don't send the data in binary form or in a simple ASCII protocol and then convert it to C# objects? You can use LINQ to access the data. In my opinion, in this case XML introduces an unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

There are tradeoffs either way, so the right choice depends on your application, how powerful your device is and who is going to be using this protocol.

You mention that the alternative is a binary-serialized, request-response approach. I think that there are two separate dimensions here: the serialization format (binary or XML) and the communication style. You can use whatever serialization format you want in either a push protocol or in a request-response protocol.

XML might be a good choice if

- Readability is important
- If there is variation between devices, i.e. if you have different devices that have different properties, since XML tends to be self-describing.
- Or if you want to publish your device's data to the Internet.

Of course, XML is verbose and there are certainly ways to accomplish all of the above with a binary protocol (e.g. with tagged values can be used to make your binary protocol more descriptive).

Answer (score 0):

One of the founders of this very site has some sane and amusing opinions on XML in [XML: The Angle Bracket Tax](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/xml-the-angle-bracket-tax.html)

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar in a previous design with PC to microprocessor communications using an XML format.  It worked very well on the PC side since what Adobe Flex (what we were using) could interpret XML very easily, and I suspect .Net can do the same thing very easily.

The more complicated part of it was on the microprocessor side.  The XML parsing had to be done manually, which was not really that complicated, but just time intensive.  Creating the XML string can also be quite a lot of code depending on what you're doing.

Overall - If I had to do it again, I still think XML was a good choice because it is a very flexible protocol.  RAM was not that much of an issue with regards to storing a few packets in our FIFO buffer on the microprocessor side but that may be something to consider in your application.

Answer (score 0):

It's a waste of precious embedded CPU time to generate and transmit XML files.  Instead, I would just use an array of binary bytes represent the data, but I would use structs to help interpret the data.  The struct feature of C# lets you easily interpret an array of bytes as meaningful data.  Here's an example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct DeviceStatus
{
    public UInt16 position;    // Byte 0 and 1
    public Byte counter;       // Byte 2
    public Fruit currentFruit; // Byte 3
};

enum Fruit : Byte
{
    Off = 0,
    Apple = 1,
    Orange = 2,
    Banana = 3,
}
```

Then you would have a function that converts your array of bytes to this struct:

```
public unsafe DeviceStatus getStatus()
{
    byte[] dataFromDevice = fetchStatusFromDevice();
    fixed (byte* pointer = dataFromDevice)
    {
        return *(DeviceStatus*)pointer;
    }
}
```

Compared to XML, this method will save CPU time on the device and on the PC, and it is easier to maintain than an XML schema, with complementary functions for building and parsing the XML file.  All you have to do is make sure that the struct and enum definitions in your embdedded device are the same as the definitions in your C# code, so that the C# program and device agree on the protocol to use.

You'll probably want to use the "packed" attribute on both the C# and embedded side so that all the struct elements are positioned in a predictable way.